# How to Schedule a save to a PDF and Excel file in VBA and then reset

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks, autosave

I'm using VBA for the first time, so bear with me.

I have an excel file which will be open 24/7. Everyday, day shift and night shift will enter things into specific cells in this file that they will not be able to edit. I've achieved this with the following code that I found online:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cl As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abcd"

For Each cl In Target

    If cl.Value <> "" Then

    check = MsgBox("Is this entry correct? This cell cannot be edited after entering a value")

        If check = vbYes Then

        cl.Locked = True

        Else

        cl.Value = ""

    End If

End If

Next cl

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abcd"

End Sub
```

What I want to do now is set a specific save time to a PDF file, (end of day shift, end of night shift) and an excel save file for the warehouse manager. I also want the file to reset to the original unfilled version after the save...and I need to generate a name with a date for each save file.

I don't even know where to begin.

I could probably figure it out eventually, but some help would be appreciated as I'm shooting blind here.

Comment: You wouldn't need to edit the code you have, it works fine. You'd add new code below it, here's an answer that should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149428/2727437

Comment: Essentially you'll just add `Application.OnTime TimeValue("<the time>"), "macro_save"` and add another macro to be called to save it

Comment: thanks, that was pretty simple i guess, is there any way for me to determine the name of the save file based on a value in a cell? (date)

Comment: im not sure i understand what youre asking. does the cell have the filename in it or are you just asking in general if you're able to capture the name and put it into a cell?

Comment: Basically every file that will be saved is a document that needs to be signed by individuals taking responsibility for the accuracy of the information, so I can't actually delete or overwrite any of the files. the idea i had was to reference the "date" in the worksheet to use as a name

Comment: Sub Macro_savens()
'
' Macro_savens Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    ChDir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save\DM180720.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\User\Desktop\macro save\DM180720PDF.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub

Comment: i "stepped into the macro", but i'm not sue how to reference a cell now or if it's even something i can do

Comment: Oh so you just want to save a separate copy of the file with the date in it each time that a user "verifies" it?

Comment: this is a daily file, i'll be setting the times at 6 in the morning and evening, day shift and night shift team leaders sign a physical copy for their shift, but  i still need the electronic versions for convenience sake. so yeah, separately with dates and time as a name...is the jedi i'm looking for

Comment: Then you’ll just have something like `...Filename:=”C:\Folder\Main Filename”&Range(“A1”).Value&”.xlsm”, FileFormat...`. It’ll be tricky to simply get the user’s name with the information I have now. Honestly I’d say that problem is probably worth opening a second question if it’s important to you.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you so much, you saved me a few hours of a headache